# Loop through contents of txt file to find match in 2nd txt file (Mac OS or Linux)

Tags: linux, macos, parsing, text-parsing, txt

Searched the site and couldn't find what I need. I have two .txt files, each with a single value on each line separated by a linebreak.

| 1st TXT File | 2nd TXT File |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | value3 |
| value2 | value4 |
| value3 | value5 |
| ... | value6 |
| ... | value7 |
| ... | value8 |

In Mac OS or Linux, how do I loop through every line of the 1st .txt file and find a corresponding value in the 2nd .txt file? Ideally, I'd like to output a final.txt that only shows the values that were found.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -o -f 1sttxtfile 2ndtxtfile >  final.txt
```

Use the contents of the first file as search terms to find in the second file by using the -f flag. Print only the matches with -o

Comment: The `-o` isn't necessary here. `-o` tells grep to show, for each matching line, only the portion of it that matched the search pattern, rather than the whole line. But in this case, the 'portion' that matches *is* the whole line, so the `-o` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this where a.txt is the left file and b.txt is the right file. Run this in a terminal, in the same folder as the files are located:

```
for token in `cat a.txt`                                                      
do 
    grep $token b.txt
done
```

If you want the output into a file then you can add tee for example:

```
for token in `cat a.txt`
do 
    grep $token b.txt | tee -a final.txt
done
```

Comment: Works, but selected other answer because of its one-line answer. Everyone loves a good one-liner.  :)

Comment: In one line: `for token in \`cat a.txt\`; do; grep $token b.txt; done`

Comment: Thanks @stalet! :)  Doing a little bit more reading and it seems that the consensus is that grep is a faster process, but thank you!